# How to solve error message "abort: repository default-push not found! " in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, repository, push, hgrc

I am new to Mercurial and tried to push a test file to a repository online.
I have encountered an error message as `abort: repository default-push not found!`
 when I tried to use `hg push` command.
I have searched online and most of the answers mentioned to configure the .hg/hgrc file.
I have done it and checked my .hg/hgrc file. It did have something as

```
[paths]
default = https://ALab@bitbucket.org/Alab/analysis
[web]
cacerts = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

To clarify my question, here are a few steps I performed and error messages I got. My machine is a RedHat Linux 5 server with default Python 2.4.3 installed. I have built a directory for Mercurial at `/home/Cassie/CassieDir/analysis` and a repository at bitbucket.org as analysis with username ALab. I have typed `commit` command and other `hg status` commands. They all seem fine. Then, I first created a dummy file called README and tried to push it at `/analysis` directory by

```
hg push
```

The error message showed:

```
abort: certificate checking requires Python 2.6
```

Then, to avoid certificate error, I then typed

```
hg push --insecure
```

The error message showed as

```
Not trusting file /home/Cassie/CassieDir/analysis/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user Cassie, group Cassie
Not trusting file /home/Cassie/CassieDir/analysis/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user Cassie, group Cassie
Not trusting file /home/Cassie/CassieDir/analysis/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user Cassie, group Cassie
abort: repository default-push not found!
```

I also typed "hg push -vv" and outputs is the same as above.

Thank you very much and please let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: double check for typos?  maybe repostoryName should be repositoryName?

Comment: what is the output of ?`hg push -vv` ?

Comment: Originally, when I did "hg push", it gave error message as "abort:certificate checking requires Python 2.6" so I used a "hg push --insecure" command. However, after doing it, when I pushed again, it then gave me error message as "Not trusting file /home/Cassie/aExperiment/aNewdirectory/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user Cassie, group Cassie ,abort: repository default-push not found!"

Comment: Could then please give exactly the commands you're typing and the exact error message ? You can update your post for doing so. Also, what OS are you using and what is the user you're using ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems the `.hg/hgrc` file doesn't belong to the correct user.

The error message says that the file belong to a user names `Cassie` which is in the `Cassie` group. You can either use this particular user to do the push or change the ownership of the file with the `chown` command. To know which user "you are", you can use the `whoami` command.

If you want more information about trust issues, you can read the [dedicated page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Trust) on the Mercurial wiki.

A third solution to your problem is described on this page, you can add either the user `Cassie` or the group with the same name to your "trusted" list. Edit, or create, a `hgrc` file in your home directory containing the following :

```
[trusted]
users = Cassie
```

But changing the ownership of the `.hgrc` file to the correct user is by far a better solution !

Comment: Thank you a million! I just realized I push as a root user at my machine. Once I change to user "Cassie", it seems fine now. You are a godsend~ Good luck for all my linux fellows who are struggling now.:P

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with this after creating a new repo. I had to add this to my /.hg/hgrc:

```
[paths]
default_push = <foopath>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when a previous clone had been aborted.
It had a .hg folder by not .hgrc file and many other things were missing.